# Pandas - Merge and Groupby different dataframes and create new columns

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

Have  `n`  number of dataframes with `n` number of `City` columns.

df1:

```
 ID      City      City1    City2     ....   CityN
 444x    Lima                DC
 222x    Rica      Dallas
 555x    Rio       London
 333x    NYC       Tokyo
 777x    SF                 Nairobi
```

df2:

```
 ID      City      City1    City2     ....    CityN
 000x    Lima                Miami
 888x    Cct      Texas
 999x    Delhi
 444x    Tokyo     Ktm
 333x    Aus                 Paris
```

dfN:

```
 ID      City      City1    City2     ....   CityN
 444x    Lima                DC
 333x    Rica      Dallas
 555x    Rio       London
 666x    NYC       Tokyo
 777x    SF                 Nairobi
```

I have tried merging the dataframes one by one but the `City` column values get overwritten by the last dataframe values.

`dfOutput=df1.merge(df2, how='left', on='ID')`

What I would like is retain all these `City1, City2, ...CityN`  column values. I have listed the example output below.

```
 ID      City1    City2    City3  City4     City5     City6
 444x    Tokyo     Lima     DC     Miami     Ktm
 333x    NYC       Tokyo     Aus     Paris   Rica     Dallas
```

And so on for the remaining `IDs`. I also tried using `groupbyID` provided from another question here in SO.

`cities = df.groupby('ID')['City'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series([city for city in x])).unstack()`

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Where's KTM for 444x?

Comment: Thanks @itzy, edited it. I have some sensitive values so had to use placeholder values.

Comment: It looks like you just want unique cities for each ID. Might be easier to just iterate over rows and read values into a dictionary and then create a DataFrame at the end.

Comment: Yeah, I thought of that and am currently working on it. I was wondering if SO could help with another solution as well.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you could use `pd.merge` without `left` parameter:

```
In [14]: df1
Out[14]: 
     ID  City   City1    City2
0  444x  Lima       -       DC
1  222x  Rica  Dallas        -
2  555x   Rio  London        -
3  333x   NYC   Tokyo        -
4  777x    SF       -  Nairobi

In [15]: df2
Out[15]: 
     ID   City  City1  City2
0  000x   Lima      -  Miami
1  888x    Cct  Texas      -
2  999x  Delhi      -      -
3  444x  Tokyo    Ktm      -
4  333x    Aus      -  Paris

In [16]: pd.merge(df1, df2, on='ID')
Out[16]: 
     ID City_x City1_x City2_x City_y City1_y City2_y
0  444x   Lima       -      DC  Tokyo     Ktm       -
1  333x    NYC   Tokyo       -    Aus       -   Paris
```

Then you could rename your columns for the resulting dataframe:

```
cols = ['ID'] + ['City' + str(i) for i in range(1, len(df3.columns))]

In [21]: cols
Out[21]: ['ID', 'City1', 'City2', 'City3', 'City4', 'City5', 'City6']
```